Не могу разобрать с типами PHP
Всем доброго времени суток! по Api получаю массив со списком товара, перебираю его с помощью foreach и данные из исходного массива пытаюсь присвоить своему итоговому массиву. Казалось бы ничего сложного, но выдает ошибку, что невозможно взять свойство у строки, хотя при проверке через dd() выдает что это массив.
foreach ($part_stock['stocks'] as $stockItem) {
   foreach ($stockItem as $item) {
      dd($item);//вот здесь выдает array
      $this->finalArr['crosses']['stocks'] = [
          'id' => $item['id']//здесь пишет Cannot access offset of type string on string
      ];
   }
}


Используйте отладку кода (или банально var_dump($item)) и смотрите что у вас там находится. Возможно Действительно на одной из итераций в $item иногда просто строка (например надпись "нет на складе" или подобное)

Возможный дубликат вопроса: Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?

dd($item) --- неправильный подход, т.к. dd сразу убивает процесс и никакие итерации дальше не идут. Надо либо var_dump либо через отладку смотреть.... проще всего будет вообще сделать print_r($part_stock['stocks']) и взглянуть на объект

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! как задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask //начните с заголовка пожалуйста

да действительно, все как всегда оказалось совсем просто, уровень вложенности разный был, спасибо
